# Netty 4 WebSocket App, Threads, Synchronization

Tags: java, netty

I have a websocket application I am working on. [Here is the code for the Netty Handler.](https://github.com/robottaway/nettyfun/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blueleftistconstructor/applug/UserApplicationHandler.java)

In it the websockets connect to a long running thread which collects them and passes back messages.

My question concerns synchronization. So when the Netty app adds a new ctx to the thread I use a lock to synchronize add/remove/iteration of the list. I don't think there is any other way around this locking.

So my question is are there any better ways to handle this sort of synchronization to the thread?

Also, is there any major performance drawbacks to doing this locking? What sort of issues can that cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is the DefaultChannelGroup[1] for group channels and write to all of them. Another cool thing about it is that the Channel will get removed automatically once it close.

[1] http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.html

Comment: btw, does netty use epoll or libevent or?

Comment: Thanks Norman! That is exactly what I want. I will use this for the interim between the Threaded app and the connections.

Comment: @user1361315 It uses epoll via Java NIO API.